# Cannot get a result other than "Too High" for a guessing game in c

Tags: c

I have finished my code for a program that allows a user to enter a range of values to guess from, then randomly generates the number, and then allows the user to guess and reports too low, too high, or correct. When I test run the program, I only get outputs of "Too high." and I've tried debugging and looking at my code but I can't see where it went wrong. Any help is much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int min, max, number, guess, count = 0;

    printf("Please enter two integers for the range:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &min, &max);

    number = (min + rand()%(max - min + 1));
    printf("I'm thinking of a number between %d and %d.\n", min, max);

    printf("Enter your guess:\n");
    scanf("%d", &guess);

    while(guess != number)
    {

        if(guess < number)
        {
            count++;
            printf("Too low.\n");
            printf("Enter your guess:\n");
            scanf("%d", &guess);
        }

        else
        {
            count++;
            printf("Too high.\n");
            printf("Enter your guess:\n");
            scanf("%d", &guess);
        }
    }

        count++;
        printf("Correct, it took you %d tries to guess my number. ", count);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you tried with too large numbers and you've been the victim of integer overflow? Also, the `count++` and `scanf()` lines should be **outside** the if statement in the loop. Furthermore, this FPEs if the lower bound is the same as the higher bound (since you are trying to divide modulo zero).

Comment: Works fine for me too, though very predictable.  You might want to provide a seed to rand() that varies with each execution.

Comment: Note the `if (guess == number)` at the end is redundant: if you've made it out of the while loop, then `guess` must be equal to `number`, so there's no point checking for it.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that makes more sense. Also H2CO3 I followed your advice and my first test run now works (the range is 1 to 100), however with a range 50 to 90 I get all "Too low" as results.

Answer (score 1):

Uh oh, you didn't initialize your random number generator!

Add `srand(time(NULL))` at the beginning of your program or your random number will always be the same (and it might well be zero).

Answer (score 1):

Your expression for `number` can generate values way out of range.  It should be:

```
number = min + rand() % (max - min + 1);
```

You also need to take steps to initialize your random number generator.