# Incorrect output on program for a guessing game

Tags: c

I have run two test sets of ranges for a guessing game,
1) 1 to 100
and
2) 50 to 90.

The first set gives the correct output, but my second test range outputs "Too High" only as a result, where as it should run 8 values through that are too low, a ninth that is too high, and then guess correctly on the 10th try.

Here's my code, and any help at all is really appreciated, thanks!

#### Version 1

Original code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int min, max, number, guess, count = 0;

    printf("Please enter two integers for the range:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &min, &max);

    number = (min + rand()%(max - min + 1));
    printf("I'm thinking of a number between %d and %d.\n", min, max);

    printf("Enter your guess:\n");
    scanf("%d", &guess);

    while(guess != number)
    {

        if(guess < number)
        {
            count++;
            printf("Too low.\n");
            printf("Enter your guess:\n");
            scanf("%d", &guess);
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
            printf("Too high.\n");
            printf("Enter your guess:\n");
            scanf("%d", &guess);
        }
    }

    count++;
    printf("Correct, it took you %d tries to guess my number. ", count);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Version 2

Modified code based on feedback from answers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int min, max, number, guess, count = 0;

    printf("Please enter two integers for the range:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &min, &max);

    srand(time(NULL));
    number = (min + rand()%(max - min + 1));
    printf("I'm thinking of a number between %d and %d.\n", min, max);
    scanf("%d", &guess);

    do
    {
        printf("Enter your guess:\n");
        scanf("%d", &guess);

        if ( guess < number)
        {
            printf("Too low.\n");
        }
        else if ( guess > number)
        {
            printf("Too high.\n");
        }
    }
    while (guess != number && count++);

    count++;
    printf("Correct, it took you %d tries to guess my number. ", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What range does `rand()` return, and what does the `%` operator do?  To help you debug, I would add in `printf` outputting the number the program has thought of.

Comment: Can you clarify what your test sets are?

Comment: Yes, forgive me. Test sets are as follows:

Comment: Set 1: min is input as 1, max is input as 100, so range is 1-100, and Set 2: min input as 50, max input as 90, so range is 50-90

Comment: See also [SO 19342074](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342074/cannot-get-a-result-other-than-too-high-for-a-guessing-game-in-c).

Comment: How are you generating the input sequence that gets you 8 'too lows', a 'too high' and the 'correct' response?

Comment: Here is what it looks like with VERSION 2 running http://imgur.com/x11aJSq It is uploaded and tested from another end so I am not sure how it is generated but I believe that a series of set input values are tested just to match the program output to see if it is correct

Comment: You need to instrument your code so you can see what it is doing.  The original code in the question behaves properly AFAICT.  The revised code misbehaves because the `do while` loop termination condition is bogus (see the update to Isiebert's answer).  If you're submitting your data to a programming contest sight, you may have problems if you vary the format, but your original code (while it can certainly be improved) produces more or less the correct answer.  You didn't include a newline at the end of the 'correct' line — that might upset the test-bot.

Comment: Alright, I've reverted to my original code (*and added \n in my correct line) and I am just going to be happy with one of two test runs coming out successfully. That said, I appreciate you all helping and being patient with me as I debug here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that works for me.  At the moment, for debugging purposes, it prints out the number in the 'Guess a number between x and y' line (which can be helpful in the early stages).  It also tests for a number of error conditions which yours does not.  The 'out of range' messages are optional; the 'too low' and 'too high' messages do convey the correct information.  Notice that the code echoes the information entered — trying to debug the wrong input (you thought you entered A but the program thinks you entered B) can lead to endless debugging confusion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static int get_guess(int *guess)
{
    printf("Enter your guess: ");
    if (scanf("%d", guess) != 1)
        return EOF;
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int min, max, number, guess, count = 0;
    srand(time(0));

    printf("Please the minimum and maximum values for the range: ");
    if (scanf("%d %d", &min, &max) != 2)
    {
        printf("Oops!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (min <= max)
    {
        printf("Your minimum (%d) is not smaller than your maximum (%d)\n", min, max);
        return 1;
    }

    number = (min + rand()%(max - min + 1));
    printf("I'm thinking of a number between %d and %d. (%d)\n", min, max, number);

    while (count < (max - min + 1) && get_guess(&guess) != EOF)
    {
        count++;
        if (guess < min)
            printf("%d: Your guess is smaller than the minimum (%d)\n", guess, min);
        else if (guess > max)
            printf("%d: Your guess is larger than the maximum (%d)\n", guess, max);
        else if (guess < number)
            printf("%d: Too low.\n", guess);
        else if (guess > number)
            printf("%d: Too high.\n", guess);
        else
        {
            printf("%d: Correct, it took you %d tries to guess my number.\n", guess, count);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (guess != number && count >= (max - min))
        printf("You didn't guess the number (%d) after %d tries.\n", number, count);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that your else condition always triggers when the number is equal, asking for a new number.

basically the opposite of:

```
if (guess < number)
```

is:

```
if (guess >= number)
```

you need to check for >, not >=

You can also reduce code by using a do while loop.

```
do {
    count++;  
    printf("Enter your guess:\n");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
      if ( guess < number) 
        printf("Too low.\n");
     else if ( guess > number)
          printf("Too high.\n");
   }while (guess != number);
```

edit: shouldn't have put count increment in the while test.

Comment: But it is within my while loop, which tests for NOT equivalence, thus if it is equal it would not enter the while loop where that if statement is located, it would go directly to the "Correct,..." printf statement

Comment: but your scanf happens inside the else.  So number == guess, but it still says too high and prompts for a different number.

Comment: I'd consider using a do while loop

Comment: Since `count` is 0 on the first iteration, you are going to exit the `do while` loop on the first iteration regardless, are you not?  I'm not sure I buy the first part of your analysis either. It would apply to your `do while` loop, but not to the original loop.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that is the case.. both test cases guess correctly after 2 tries when they should be more. Ill post updated code for this current suggestion, thanks

Comment: shoot that should have been ++count and not in the loop;  my bad

Comment: OK...I suppose that probably prevents the loop iterating more than about 2^32 times; otherwise, I don't see the benefit of testing `count` like that.  If you had `&& ++count < (max - min)` or something, it would make more sense.  ...And you removed the condition on `count` while I was typing this...

Comment: yeah sorry, I realized I was dumb when trying to be clever.  You are absolutely right.

Comment: 'Pro' tip: test your code, even when you think it can't possibly go wrong.  It saves face (he says, having wiped egg off his visage more than once when submitting code without testing it). By all means test just after submitting, but do test.

Answer (score 1):

`rand()` is always returning the same number (or sequence of numbers if you were to call it more than once in your program execution) because it always uses the same seed number to generate random numbers. This results in a guess numbers **always** being the same for a given test case.

To have a different seed each time you execute the program, add the line `srand(time(NULL));` before your call to `rand()`.

Comment: So I should insert it just before the line I call rand on like this?
        srand(time(NULL));

        number = (min + rand()%(max - min + 1));

Comment: Hmm.. I've done this and included <time.h>, and now my first test run is all High's. By the way, I am doing these tests by uploading to a test site, which then runs set inputs and shows the solution output side-by-side to the test output. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with this

Comment: That said, Isiebert's solution fixes the issue that you originally asked about. I'm highlighting another issue that I found in your code.

Comment: Note that the values returned by the first call to `rand()` are not standardized (so the 8 and 88 are not necessarily the correct values).  OTOH, you're absolutely correct that without a call to `srand()`, each run using the same min/max pair will have the same number to guess.